# Pass parameter to dialog in the same page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page contains a form and other form nested in a dialog.
I need to pass parameter to dialog when button clicked in the main form

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable var="form" value="#{myBean.formList}">
     <p:commandButton id="selectProduct" 
                            update="selectProductForm" oncomplete="selectProductDlg.show()" 
                            image="ui-icon-" > 
                            <f:param name="formId" value="#{form.id}" />
                </p:commandButton>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialog>
...<h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.setSelected}"
                    update="main_form"
                    oncomplete="if(#{myBean.errorText == 'SUCCESS'}){ selectProductDlg.hide();}"
                    value="Sec">
                </p:commandButton>
```

i can not see formId in myBean with code:

```
if (form == null) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            if(req.getParameter("formId") != null) {
                formId = Long.valueOf(req.getParameter("formId"));
            }
            if (formId != null && !"".equals(formId)) {
                form = formService.findById(formId);
            } 
        }
```

where am i wrong
thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that the bean is in the view scope, just set it as a bean property direclty in the action method of the command button in the datatable column.

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable var="form" value="#{myBean.formList}">
    <p:column>
      <p:commandButton id="selectProduct" 
                       action="#{myBean.setCurrentForm(form)}"
                       update="selectProductForm" oncomplete="selectProductDlg.show()" 
                       image="ui-icon-"> 
      </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialog>
  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.setSelected}"
                     update="main_form"
                     oncomplete="if(#{myBean.errorText == 'SUCCESS'}){ selectProductDlg.hide();}"
                     value="Sec">
    </p:commandButton>
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

If you have a cancel button in the dialog, you need to let its action method set it to `null`.

There's no need to fiddle around with raw HTTP request parameters in POST requests. The `<f:param>` should as much as possible be used in GET requests only (e.g. `<h:link>`, `<h:button>`, etc).

Comment: thanks very much, i used to think i can not pass parameter to action method, now i edited my code and it worked