# Pass parameter to a dialoggrid from another dialoggrid in the same page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uirepeat

I've message in an xhtml page of course bound with a bean.

Now the messages are in a list, and i'm using ui:repeat to display the message and all that. 
Now when i open a message, there's a reply button in the dialogGrid which opens another dialog on the same page, 
I just need to pass data to that reply dialog. 
In the first place, it's working fine, i mean if you click on the reply button directly it works fine, but when you open the message and then click on reply it doesn't update the dialog.

I've seen this 
[Pass parameter to dialog in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839224/pass-parameter-to-dialog-in-the-same-page)

But ***MY BEAN IS REQUEST SCOPED***

Here's my xhtml code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/homepage-style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/profile.css" />
        <title>Shadi Bandhan | We find the best match for you</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header" >
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="main-content">
            <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />

            <div id="left-pane">

                <div id="profile-info-area">
                    <ui:insert name="profile_info_area" >
                        <ui:include src="profileInfoArea.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>

                <div id="home-main-area">
                    <div id="messages-wrapper">

                        <div id="messages-header">

                            <div id="m-heading">
                                Messages - Inbox
                            </div>

                            <div id="m-search">

                                <div id="searchbox">
                                    Search Messages <input type="text" value="Search" />
                                </div>

                                <div id="newmessage">
                                    <a href="#"> + New Message </a>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <h:form id="messagesForm">
                            <div id="messages">

                                <p:dialog id="messagesDialog" modal="true" widgetVar="messageDialog" resizable="false"  width="750" height="300" header="New Message" >  

                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="dialogGrid">
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="msgRecepient"  value="To"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel id="msgRecepient" value="#{userMsg.userFullname}"  >

                                            </h:outputLabel>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="msgContents"  value="Message"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputTextarea maxlength="300"  id="msgContents" value="#{messagesManagedBean.msg.message}" cols="65" rows="3" >
                                                <p:watermark for="msgContents" value="#{userMsg.userId}" />
                                            </p:inputTextarea>


                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton id="msgSend" value="Send" action="#{messagesManagedBean.sendMessage('reply')}" oncomplete="messageDialog.hide()"  >
                                                <f:param value="#{userMsg.userId}" name="messageSenderId" />
                                            </p:commandButton> 
                                        </p:column>

                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                </p:dialog>

                                <p:dialog id="messagesDialog2" modal="true" widgetVar="messageDialog2" resizable="false"  width="750" height="300" header="New Message" >  

                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="dialogGrid2">
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="msgRecepient2"  value="From"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel id="msgRecepient2" value="#{userMsg.userFullname}"  >

                                            </h:outputLabel>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="msgContents2"  value="Message"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputTextarea readonly="true" id="msgContents2" value="#{userMsg.message}" cols="65" rows="3" >

                                            </p:inputTextarea>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton styleClass="reply-btn" value="Reply" update=":messagesForm:dialogGrid"
                                                             oncomplete="messageDialog.show(), messageDialog2.hide()">
                                                <f:param name="userMsg" value="#{userMsg}" />
                                            </p:commandButton>
                                        </p:column>

                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                </p:dialog>

                                <ui:repeat var="userMsg" value="#{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.model}">

                                    <center><img class="h-diff" src="../images/differentiator-profile.jpg" width="437" height="1" /></center>

                                    <div id="message">

                                        <div id="senderImg">
                                            <img class="senderImg" src="../images/profile-pic.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="message-txt-area">

                                            <div id="senderName">
                                                <p:commandLink styleClass="senderName" value="#{userMsg.userFullname}" action="#{myProfileManagedBean.loadProfileFrontInformation(userMsg.userId)}"></p:commandLink>
                                            </div>
                                            <ui:fragment rendered="#{userMsg.isRead}">
                                                <div id="message-txt">
                                                    #{userMsg.message}
                                                </div>
                                            </ui:fragment>
                                            <ui:fragment rendered="#{not userMsg.isRead}">
                                                <div id="message-txt" class="msgNotRead">
                                                    #{userMsg.message}
                                                </div>
                                            </ui:fragment>
                                            <div id="msgAction">

                                                <p:commandLink styleClass="reply-btn"
                                                               value="Reply" oncomplete="messageDialog.show()" update=":messagesForm:dialogGrid">
                                                    <f:param name="userMsg" value="#{userMsg}" />
                                                </p:commandLink>

                                                <ui:fragment rendered="#{userMsg.isRead}">
                                                    <p:commandLink styleClass="open-btn" value="Open" 
                                                                   oncomplete="messageDialog2.show()" update=":messagesForm:dialogGrid2">
                                                        <f:param name="userMsg" value="#{userMsg}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                </ui:fragment>

                                                <ui:fragment rendered="#{not userMsg.isRead}">
                                                    <p:commandLink styleClass="open-btn" value="Open" 
                                                                   action="#{messagesManagedBean.messageOpenedListener(userMsg.messageId)}" 
                                                                   oncomplete="messageDialog2.show()" update=":messagesForm:dialogGrid2">
                                                        <f:param name="userMsg" value="#{userMsg}" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                </ui:fragment>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </ui:repeat>
                                <h:commandButton value="&lt; prev" action="#{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.prev}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.pageIndex} / #{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.pages}"/>
                                <h:commandButton value="next &gt;" action="#{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.next}"/>
                                <h:inputHidden value="#{messagesManagedBean.paginator1.pageIndex}"/>

                            </div>
                        </h:form>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="right-pane">
                <ui:insert name="right-pane" >
                    <ui:include src="right-pane.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer" >
                <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you need to keep your bean with RequestScope? Can't you change it to ViewScope?

Comment: No, i can't. I need all the data in the page on each and every request.

Comment: The ViewScope can do that too. What's the problem?

Comment: let's just say it's the requirement of the client that the bean be request scoped. if you can please answer my question. thanks