# jsf 2 passing of value to dialog not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, view-scope

I want to pass a value to a dialog but it wont work. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839224/pass-parameter-to-dialog-in-the-same-page) approach but no luck

Here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:inputText value="#{myManagedBean.input}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="edit" onclick="dlg.show()"/>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">
                passed value:<p:inputText value="#{myManagedBean.input}"/>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and my managedbean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private String input;

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set value in "input" field. after you need to show your dialog box.

you can do it like. Change your code According to this code.

**Please Notice "immediate" and "oncomplete" Attribute.**

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            Input : <p:inputText value="#{myBean.input}" immediate="true"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Sumbit" oncomplete="dlg.show()" update=":form2"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="form2">
            <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">
                passed value:<p:inputText value="#{myBean.input}"/>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change the bean name, sorry, its working now, tnx ^^