# How to open dialog window to edit user in jsf page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I have a condition where in ui:repeat on button click i'm setting the values into      inputHidden using javascript. I want that to open in a popup window to edit. I'm trying to open show_dialog after setting values in javascript block .here's my code

```
<ui:repeat var="c" value="#{abc.getabcList()}" varStatus="status">
        .................code.........
        <h:commandButton value="Edit" onclick="setSelectedValuesForEdit('#{c.name}','#{c.address}'"></h:commandButton>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
function setSelectedValuesForEdit(nameValue,addressValue)
    {           
        document.getElementById("abclist:name").value=nameValue;
        document.getElementById("abclist:address").value=addressValue;
show_dialog('/xyz/faces/path.xhtml','Abc inputs',410,430);
}
```

And i have set inputHidden in page .And i'm able to see the values set to input hidden when i do viewsource.

But how to open this in popup window to edit..where i'm trying to open a Jquery show_dialog(.....)as in above code.

Comment: This functionality is not supported out-of-the-box for JSF2. Are you using a JSF conmponent toolkit, e.g. RichFaces, IceFaces, PrimeFaces?

Comment: well, maybe you can open a with window.open (like a popUp) in the action of command button,  linked with a new bean, that just define the objecte that you wanna change, in yopur case the selected object.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao i'm able to open popup window using the JQuery popup...but my issue is i'm not able to pass the hidden values into that popup..

Comment: there is similar question with primeFaces, maybe can help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988038/jsf-2-passing-of-value-to-dialog-not-working